# python API coding for tidal music

Tags: python, api

Hi currently a student working on a project for school.

I'm looking to use a music API to work with, and have found TidalAPI. However, my code can't seem to run.

Below is my code:

```
import tidalapi

def logindetails():
    username = input("What is your Tidal username? ")
    password = input("What is your Tidal password? ")
    session = tidalapi.Session()
    session.login(username, password)

def gettingalbum():
    logindetails()
    album_id = input("What is the album ID? ")

    tracks = session.get_album_tracks(album_id)
    print("Tracks in this album are:")
    x = 0
    for track in tracks:
        x = x+1
        print(x,track.name)

gettingalbum()
```

NameError: name 'session' is not defined for session.get_album_tracks(album_id)

how can I link my first module with the second?

(It works if I combine both codes into one module, but I have to split them into 2 modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest making `logindetails()` return the logged-in session you can then pass into other functions. (The other option would be to make it a global variable.)

I also took the liberty of adding the use of  `enumerate()` for printing the track indexes.

```
import tidalapi


def logindetails():
    """
    Ask for login details and return a logged-in session.
    """
    username = input("What is your Tidal username? ")
    password = input("What is your Tidal password? ")
    session = tidalapi.Session()
    session.login(username, password)
    return session


def gettingalbum(session):
    album_id = input("What is the album ID? ")

    tracks = session.get_album_tracks(album_id)
    print("Tracks in this album are:")
    for x, track in enumerate(tracks, 1):
        print(x, track.name)


session = logindetails()
gettingalbum(session)
```

Comment: The logindetails() inside the gettingalbum() method is no longer required right? In fact, since the session might change I suspect this to break or cause odd errors. I do agree with the solution of actually returning the session in the logindetails method.

Comment: @Ludo21South Oh yeah, missed that. Removed now.